# How can I open cmd in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I know, that it possible to write python code in postgresql with PL/Python Functions.
Is it possible to call cmd command from postgresql? I need to use pg_repack, not from terminal as usual, but from procedures from postgresql.

Comment: You probably can. But I didn't try it. https://github.com/petere/plsh

Comment: Consider using pg_squeeze instead, which does not need a client component.